Coral Ordinal AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'
I am working on a project that uses ordinal regression/classification in Python and Tensorflow. I found the pip package coral-ordinal that implements ordinal regression and includes useful loss functions. However when going through their tutorial on Google Colab  I get the error
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name' 

when running model.fit().
This error occurs when I attempt to use it in other code as well. The code up to where the error takes place is as follows
import tensorflow as tf
print("Tensorflow version", tf.__version__)

import coral_ordinal as coral
print("CORAL Ordinal version:", coral.__version__)

##########################
### SETTINGS
##########################

# Hyperparameters
random_seed = 1 # Not yet used
learning_rate = 0.05
batch_size = 128
num_epochs = 2

# Architecture
NUM_CLASSES = 10

# Fetch and format the mnist data
(mnist_images, mnist_labels), (mnist_images_test, mnist_labels_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

# Split off a validation dataset for early stopping
from sklearn import model_selection
mnist_images, mnist_images_val, mnist_labels, mnist_labels_val = \
  model_selection.train_test_split(mnist_images, mnist_labels, test_size = 5000, random_state = 1)

print("Shape of training images:", mnist_images.shape)
print("Shape of training labels:", mnist_labels.shape)

print("Shape of test images:", mnist_images_test.shape)
print("Shape of test labels:", mnist_labels_test.shape)

print("Shape of validation images:", mnist_images_val.shape)
print("Shape of validation labels:", mnist_labels_val.shape)

# Also rescales to 0-1 range.
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
  (tf.cast(mnist_images[..., tf.newaxis] / 255, tf.float32),
   tf.cast(mnist_labels, tf.int64)))
dataset = dataset.shuffle(1000).batch(batch_size)

test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
  (tf.cast(mnist_images_test[..., tf.newaxis] / 255, tf.float32),
   tf.cast(mnist_labels_test, tf.int64)))
#test_dataset = test_dataset.shuffle(1000).batch(batch_size)
# Here we do not shuffle the test dataset.
test_dataset = test_dataset.batch(batch_size)


val_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
  (tf.cast(mnist_images_val[..., tf.newaxis] / 255, tf.float32),
   tf.cast(mnist_labels_val, tf.int64)))
val_dataset = val_dataset.shuffle(1000).batch(batch_size)

def create_model(num_classes):
  model = tf.keras.Sequential()
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape = (28, 28, )))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation = "relu"))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation = "relu"))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1))
  # Ordinal output layer with a certain number of classes / ranks / labels.
  # No activation function specified so this will output cumulative logits.
  model.add(coral.CoralOrdinal(num_classes))
  return model

model = create_model(NUM_CLASSES)

# Note that the model generates 1 fewer outputs than the number of classes. 
model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = learning_rate),
              loss = coral.OrdinalCrossEntropy(num_classes = NUM_CLASSES),
              metrics = [coral.MeanAbsoluteErrorLabels()])


# This takes about 5 minutes on CPU, 2.5 minutes on GPU.
history = model.fit(dataset, epochs = 5, validation_data = val_dataset,
                    callbacks = [tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience = 3, restore_best_weights = True)])

How to fix this? I would raise on issue on their github, but the last response was 2 years ago so I'm doubtful the maintainers would respond.
Alternatively, if there isn't any realistic options for getting this work, are there any alternatives that could help with ordinal regression/classification in tensorflow?
